# Can't run jflex.bat in windows 8.1

Tags: java, batch-file, javac, jflex, cup

I just made the installation of jflex and cup and I want to test if everything is ok. 
Here is what I write in the shell and the result I get.
[image]

Here is the content of jflex.bat file:
[image]
Is there something I have done wrong?
How to run for first time jflex? When I write java -version it displays the correct version of java in my pc. THe problem is with jflex.

Thanks!

Comment: Please include graphics by using the `picture` icon (like a landscape) so that future readers may see what the data was. Best to cut-and-paste code snippets, then select and press `{}` to mark as code. That way, your code is editable and doesn't have to be retyped with consequent saving in typos.

Comment: ...or you could have copy-pasted the text from the console into your question. Because there is no way for a future user to find your question by searching the error message shown in a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you are executing `%java_home%\bin`, you should

1) Enclose `%java_home%\bin\java` in "Double Quotes"
2) Likewise, enclose `%clpath%` in "Double Quotes"

That way, `cmd` is aware that the contents between the quotes is a single string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to surround the value of the JAVA_HOME variable with double quotes because it contains spaces
The `JAVA_HOME` variable that contains the path to the root-directory of your java environment contains spaces: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java`. It is used at the 3rd last line:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -classpath...
```

So by just substituting the value of `%JAVA_HOME%` you get:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\bin\java -classpath...
```

You would say: "it's just a path to the java executable". But that's not how the command interpreter sees it, it will think you are giving 3 different things: `C:\Program` `Files` `(x86)` (it just takes the whitespace as separator for arguments as usual!). It then will take the first one `C:\Program` as the path to an executable program and the rest of the line as its arguments. Because `C:\Program` is not the path to a valid executable you get the error

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an external or internal command`

So to let it know he always has to see the `C:\Program Files (x86)` as a whole (part of a same thing: one path to a directory) you just surround it with double quotes. In batch it is always wise to surround variables with double quotes when they represent a path! Now you have 3 options:

1. The most easy one (will only solve this specific problem): replace

   ```
   set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java
   ```

   with

   ```
   set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java"
   ```

   This way you make sure everywhere JAVA_HOME is used, you will get no more problems because of the spaces arround "Files"
2. Go everywhere you used `%JAVA_HOME%` and replace it with `"%JAVA_HOME%"` (just surround with double quotes). You can do the same for all usages of `%JFLEX_HOME%` as this also represents a path
3. The last option (the most general, one you should consider as a rule in batch) surround all representations of paths (literal paths or paths set in variables) with double quotes.

Comment: But the java is Ok. When I write java -version it displays the correct version of java in my pc. THe problem is with jflex.

Comment: There is no problem with your java (or at least ... it is not what causes the error)

Comment: I edited my answer and provided some more explanation, hope it helps you to understand the problem and to solve it :)